# Centering rotated bar chart value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

Using the following bar chart

[image: Bar chart]

one can see that the label isn't really centered over the bar but placed more on the right. How can I center the value? The alignment has to be like that (rotated and over the bar) because of other data values which is not in the minimal example which is here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,german,notitlepage]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon,header=false]{
Entry;0.008
}\data

\pgfplotsset{
percentage plot/.style={
    point meta=explicit,
every node near coord/.append style={
    align=center,
    text width=1cm
},
    nodes near coords={
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
    \ifnum\iszero=0
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\
    \fi},
    yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=0.5,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0},
visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
},
percentage series/.style={
    table/y expr=\thisrow{#1},table/meta=#1
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.95\textwidth,
ylabel=y axis,
xlabel=x axis,
percentage plot,
ybar,
every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west, font=\scriptsize},
symbolic x coords={Entry,
},
x tick label style={font=\normalsize, rotate=90, anchor=east},
enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
xtick=data
]
\addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Edit:
Corrected code. Now it should compile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I am getting compile errors. Please correct the [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301). Ideally you should also eliminate as much as possible that is not needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. Code corrected.

Comment: You get the correct result by commenting `every node near coord/.append style` stuff in `percentage plot/.style`. Unfortunately with the given example it is unclear for what that is good for ...

Comment: What might also help is looking at the difference of `font` and `node font` in the [TikZ manual section 17.4.2 (on page 233 in v3.1.9a](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#subsubsection.17.4.2).

Comment: if I comment "every node near coord/.append style" nothing changes. I don't get an error but the alignment stays the same (using pdflatex with texmaker)

Comment: even with the manual unfortunately I can't get it right. Using align= only left works. Seems like I'm missing something or don't understand it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

---

When I comment `every node near coord/.append style` (as mentioned in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624676/centering-rotated-bar-chart-value#comment1559435_624676))

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        percentage plot/.style={
            point meta=explicit,
%            every node near coord/.append style={
%                align=center,
%%                text width=1cm,
%            },
            nodes near coords={
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
                \ifnum\iszero=0
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\
                \fi%
            },
            yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=0.5,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0},
            visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
        },
        percentage series/.style={
            table/y expr=\thisrow{#1},table/meta=#1
        },
    }
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon,header=false]{
        Entry;0.008
    }\data
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.95\textwidth,
        ylabel=y axis,
        xlabel=x axis,
        percentage plot,
        ybar,
        every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west, font=\scriptsize},
        symbolic x coords={Entry},
        x tick label style={font=\normalsize, rotate=90, anchor=east},
        enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
        xtick=data,
    ]
        \addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image: image showint the result of above code]

which looks like what you are expecting. This works for pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 0):

Unsing this code

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotsset{
        percentage plot/.style={
            point meta=explicit,
%            every node near coord/.append style={
%                align=center,
%%                text width=1cm,
%            },
            nodes near coords={
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\iszero{\originalvalue==0}
                \ifnum\iszero=0
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=3]{\originalvalue}$\,\%$\\
                \fi%
            },
            yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,$\%$,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=0.5,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0},
            visualization depends on={y \as \originalvalue}
        },
        percentage series/.style={
            table/y expr=\thisrow{#1},table/meta=#1
        },
    }
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon,header=false]{
        Entry;0.008
        Entry2;0.4
        Entry3;0.3
    }\data
    \begin{axis}[
        width=0.95\textwidth,
        ylabel=y axis,
        xlabel=x axis,
        percentage plot,
        ybar,
        every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west, font=\scriptsize},
        symbolic x coords={Entry, Entry2, Entry3},
        x tick label style={font=\normalsize, rotate=90, anchor=east},
        enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
        xtick=data,
    ]
        \addplot table [percentage series=1] {\data};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that I'm using \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} as 1.18 doesn't work (in my configuration. Don't know why, yet). I think it is not really centered. Maybe it may be a bit fussy. You can see it on Entry 3. But for now I'm using it like this and it can stay like this.

[image]

Comment: Why do you write that "1.18 doesn't work"? I do not have any problem with this code in 1.18.

Comment: I meant only in my envorinment. I get an error message if I try to use it. Same was for 1.16. Unfortunately I cannot do some research for now to check why this is the case.